# Java 8 Iterate over Map.Entry and create and return List of new Object

Tags: java, java-8

How can I achieve the logic below using java8?

```
List<GenericKeyValueHolder<Integer>> r = searchAttributes.rowMap().forEach((id, value) -> {
        new GenericKeyValueHolder<T>(id, value);
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stream over the `entrySet` of the `Map`, map each entry to your target type and collect to a `List`:

```
List<GenericKeyValueHolder<Integer>> r = 
    searchAttributes.rowMap()
                    .entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .map(e -> new GenericKeyValueHolder<>(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```